# Where do I put Imports in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am trying to import the following:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

In order to be able to use "`Dataset()`"

I am a beginner and don't know where to put the imports in ASP.NET. Please help!

Maybe these are not necessary? I am trying to import a remote XML file into a DropDownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes at the top of your class file.  The .CS file associated to your page.  Right-click on the ASPX file and click View Code.  There should already be several imports statements in that file by default.

Answer (score 1):

Put it above the declaration of your class.